# Listen events on parent model with eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have common class for all my models.

class Base extends Model;

class A extends Base;

class B extends Base;

I can listen `saving` on each model, `A::saving(callback()` but it does not seem to work to listen on Base. `Base::saving(callback)`.

```
<?php


class BaseModel extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
{


}


class A extends BaseModel
{
    protected $table = 'a';
}

class B extends BaseModel
{

    protected $table = 'b';
}


class BusinessLogicProvider extends \Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider
{

    /**
     * Register the service provider.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        A::updating(function () {
            //this fires
        });

        BaseModel::updating(function(){
            //this never fires
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post your model classes?

Comment: models are pretty large. I added a code to express my idea better. I do not not if Eloquent was suppose to work like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work with inheritance because the event system doesn't work that way. When you register a model event listener, it only listens for that model but not the extensions of it.

**`\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` line 1281:**

```
protected static function registerModelEvent($event, $callback, $priority = 0)
{
    if (isset(static::$dispatcher)) {
        $name = get_called_class();
        static::$dispatcher->listen("eloquent.{$event}: {$name}", $callback, $priority);
    }
}
```

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L1281

Comment: I know that A inherits from BaseModel, that I was looking for, to be able to listen all models that inherit same class. Is there any other way of doing this?

Comment: Oh, sorry I got it all wrong. I'll look into the problem and see if I can come up with something.

Comment: I know that it works using a trait on the model, listening on static::..., but is too hidden and when testing those models you have your models too connected with the callbacks of the events

Answer (score 0):

I came up a solution with `forward_static_call()` function:

```php
        $classes = [
            \App\Models\XinFinance\ExcilerSource::class,
            \App\Models\XinFinance\ExcilerVersion::class,
            \App\Models\XinFinance\ExcilerDict::class,
            \App\Models\XinFinance\ExcilerCell::class,
        ];

        foreach ($classes as $class) {
            forward_static_call(
                [$class, 'saving'],
                function ($model) {
                    // your logic...
                });
        };
```

Apparently it's not ideal, for that you must add child class manually. But that's the best way I can think of for now. Hope others can came up with a more sensible way to do this.

**UPDATES:**

I came across this article https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/listen-to-any-saveupdatecreate-event-for-any-model and so there is a better way:

In your BaseModel:

```php
    public static function boot()
    {
        static::saving(function () { // your logic... } );
        parent::boot();
    }
```